# Multiple-tag search is broken, returns results that don't have the tag(s)

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

On [the Search Help/FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), it says you can ***narrow*** your search to specific tags:
[image: tag search options]

However, when I run searches with multiple tags, I frequently get extra, erroneous results.
For example see [this search for `[greasemonkey] [iframe] user:331508`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgreasemonkey%5D%20%5Biframe%5D%20user:331508):

[(Click for larger image)

[image: search results]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X96AB.gif)

The searches are returning way too many results and the top results don't even have one of the required tags!

---

---

Note, as pointed out in the comments, this is `OR` behavior, contrary to what the Help/Faq implies.

- There are currently 19 [questions tagged both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey+iframe) [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) and [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe).
- There are currently 412 [questions matching `[greasemonkey] user:331508`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgreasemonkey%5D%20user:331508&submit=search).
- There are currently, nominally 16 questions that ***should*** be returned by the `[greasemonkey] [iframe] user:331508` query? (Note that the graphic above lists 414 hits, but it's now 415 hits.)

I have tried every variation of: `AND`, `[AND]`, and `+` that I can think of.  The search still returns incorrect results.

Comment: Lol, it exhibits `[OR]` behavior here.

Comment: Wonder if the user parameter breaks it back into OR

Comment: Yeah, this is only happening for me when combined with the user operator.

Comment: Yes, I could have swore that other parameters would break it too but, so far, only `user:` does so reliably.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question but haven't attempted to locate one. IIRC Something about it is broken if anything is included in the search other than tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  A shortcut is used direct against SQL for these types of searches that ends up, by nature, being inaccurate and OR-ing the tags.

It boils down to this:

```
And Exists(Select 1 
             From PostTags pt 
            Where p.Id = pt.PostId 
              And pt.TagId in (@tagIds1, @tagIds2, @tagIds3))
```

That means we get an effective OR in our search, and it's a very non-trivial thing to change as that's used in many code paths.  Instead of going that route, we'll submit more-than-one tag searches to Lucene and exactly 1 to SQL.  The 1 case is especially important performance-wise because it's what you get when clicking a tag from a user's profile...so it's quite common and worth optimizing.